# Javascript - ff and ie margin-top issue

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I'm making a webpage for my company, and it works great in safari and chrome..

I have a wrapper around all content of the page, and I have a javascript to detect if my wrapper is smaller than innerHeight, and then place the footer to to bottom, but for some reason, it doesn't work in IE and FF under the link "Produkter". It doesn't put the footer all the way to the buttom, like the javascript detects the wrapper to be bigger than innerHeight in this particular case, but under "Produkter" the wrapper is definitely smaller the innerHeight! ... All other places where the wrapper is smaller than innerHeight it works great, also in IE and FF..

.. In Safari and Chrome everything works like it should..

What could I be doing wrong?

Edit: forgot code and link xD

Javascript:

```
var screen_height = window.innerHeight;
var wrapper_height = document.getElementById("main-wrapper").offsetHeight;
if (wrapper_height > screen_height) {
document.getElementById("footer-wrapper").style.marginTop = 0;  
}
else {
var height_calc = screen_height - wrapper_height;
document.getElementById("footer-wrapper").style.marginTop = height_calc + "px";
}
```

Link: www.sipri.dk/siliva - if someone wants to take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though you have a bottom margin on something under "Produkter". Vertical margins on non floated elements are collapsible, which is throwing off your top margin calculation in `place_footer()`.

Putting a bottom border 1px tall on the `#wrapper` div should prevent bottom margins on elements inside that DIV from collapsing with the top margin on `#footer-wrapper`.

An alternative would be to position `#footer-wrapper` relative, and use the "top" property in CSS instead of a top margin. That would prevent any issues with collapsing margins as well.

Comment: That worked! Thanks!
..Though, something is still wrong, and this is getting to complexed for me! Help please :)

 - Take a look at the page now under the link "Kontakt".

Comment: I'm looking at "Kontakt" and I don't see anything wrong with it. Can you elaborate?

Comment: On my browsers it looks bizarre... Same in all browsers though, but wrong!
Under "kontakt" it looks like this: www.sipri.dk/siliva/kontakt.jpg
... And it is suppose to look like the footer on the other pages.. And the funny thing is that if I change it back from where I started, the "Kontakt" page works great..

Comment: There is some other issue at play. Make sure you are clearing floated elements properly. The #main-wrapper DIV is probably not the height you think it is.

Comment: Your right, the floating messed it up... Removed the floating and used position: absolute and margin-left the places that used to float..
Now it works! :D Thanks!

Comment: You may want to read up on [Clearing Floats](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html). Absolute positioning brings its own problems too.